# Combine stream of Collections into one Collection - Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

So I have a `Stream<Collection<Long>>` that I obtain by doing a series of transformations on another stream.

What I need to do is collect the `Stream<Collection<Long>>` into one `Collection<Long>`.

I could collect them all into a list like this:

```
<Stream<Collection<Long>> streamOfCollections = /* get the stream */;

List<Collection<Long>> listOfCollections = streamOfCollections.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And then I could iterate through that list of collections to combine them into one.

However, I imagine there must be a simple way to combine the stream of collections into one `Collection<Long>` using a `.map()` or `.collect()`. I just can't think of how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Look into `flatMap`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This functionality can be achieved with a call to [the `flatMap` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) on the stream, which takes a `Function` that maps the `Stream` item to another `Stream` on which you can collect.

Here, the `flatMap` method converts the `Stream<Collection<Long>>` to a `Stream<Long>`, and `collect` collects them into a `Collection<Long>`.

```
Collection<Long> longs = streamOfCollections
    .flatMap( coll -> coll.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You could also use a method reference: `.flatMap(Collection::stream)`

Answer (score 15):

You could do this by using [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) and providing a supplier (the `ArrayList::new` part):

```
Collection<Long> longs = streamOfCollections.collect(
    ArrayList::new, 
    ArrayList::addAll,
    ArrayList::addAll
);
```

Comment: @Desik Most definitely - it's what I use these days. At the time I was just learning the new streaming API.

Comment: @Desik why is it better performing than the accepted answer?

Comment: @JordanMackie Because there are less intermediate operations, and no temporary objects created. In this solution you don't call `stream()` on every collection.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify classes when not needed.
A better solution is:

```
Collection<Long> longs = streamOfCollections.collect(
    ArrayList::new,
    Collection::addAll,
    Collection::addAll
);
```

Say, you don't need an ArrayList but need a HashSet, then you also need to edit only one line.